# Query child record from parent

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 classes: `Staff` and `State`.

```
public class State {
  @Id
  private String id;
  private String name;
}

public class Staff {

  @Id
  @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition="VARCHAR(100)")
  private String id;
  private String name;
  private String phoneNo;
  private String address;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "state_id")
  private State state;
}
```

How to get query using JpaRepository to filter by `State.name`. Since it is mapped using `state_id`?

Something similar to this:

```
//current DAO to filter by staff's name
List<Staff> findByNameContaining(String name);
```

But I want to filter by `name` of `Staff` and by `name` of `State`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this.

```
List<Staff> findByNameAndState_Name(String staffName, String stateName)
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can do that as well. try to create a method as following. pass the state name.

  List findByStateName(String stateName);